# Cannot Group Certain Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range, grouping

I am trying to group a single row 494 as shown in the picture below but am not able to do so. Anything within rows 491 and 511 cannot seem to be grouped. However, I am able to group a row such as a row 514.

I am now aware that the maximum grouping level is 8. However, When I go to Column 3 to create my second level of groups it jumps to layer 3 instead of 2. How do I prevent this from happnening?

[image]

Here is the code I used to group

```
bFoundLastRow = False

For iColumn = 1 To wksSupervisor.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For iRow = 3 To wksSupervisor.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
        lastRow = wksSupervisor.Cells(10000, iColumn + 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If IsEmpty(wksSupervisor.Cells(iRow, iColumn)) And Not IsEmpty(wksSupervisor.Cells(iRow - 1, iColumn)) Then
                
            startRow = iRow
        
        End If
        
        If IsEmpty(wksSupervisor.Cells(iRow, iColumn)) And Not IsEmpty(wksSupervisor.Cells(iRow + 1, iColumn)) Then
            
            bFoundLastRow = True
            endRow = iRow
            
        End If
        
        If (bFoundLastRow = True Or iRow = lastRow) And (startRow <> endRow) Then
            endRow = iRow
            wksSupervisor.Rows(startRow & ":" & endRow).group
            bFoundLastRow = False
            
        End If
        
        If (bFoundLastRow = True Or iRow = lastRow) And (startRow = endRow) Then
            wksSupervisor.Cells(iRow, iColumn).Select
            Selection.Columns.group
            bFoundLastRow = False
            
        End If
        
    Next iRow

Next iColumn
```

Comment: The maximum level of grouping is 8, so you're basically out of luck here.

Comment: @BigBen How do I make it so when I group Column 3, it is not in level 3 but level 2?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding outline levels. When you group once, you'll see `1` and `2`. When you group twice, you'll see `1`, `2`, and `3`.